# Advice Migrating a Windows form application to a windows service / service controller

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-services

I have developed a windows forms application in vb.NET that handles Barcode scans (Barcode readers are set-up on a comm port - the application passes the codes scanned to an asp.net asmx web service that processes the scan and returns the result to the application).

The application is working great but I have been tasked with allowing the Barcode scanners to be used whilst the PC is logged off.

I have developed a prototype windows service in vb.net (.net framework 4.5) that will accept the barcode scans - currently this is writing the scan to the windows event log but this would connect to the web-service to process the scans.

This service is working with the PC logged off.

What I now need is an application that displays a user interface - i.e. I need to pop-up a window when a Barcode is scanned. I also want to be able to 'read' the collection of 'Barcode Scanner' objects that the service is handling so that they can be displayed to the user. I also need to be able to configure the windows service (set web service URL etc.).

Can anyone give me any advice on the best way of achieving this? Can the windows service 'push' information to a 'client'? if so what is the mechanism for achieving this?

Can a windows service expose methods (e.g 'GetScanners' or 'GetLastScan')? How would you set this up?

Thanks for any ideas / suggestions!

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend either of the following two options:

1. Host a WCF service from within your window's service and then have the client app reference that WCF service.  The client could then call the appropriate WCF methods to query the current status of the service or set it's properties.
2. The service could read/write all it's status and settings to and from a commonly accessible database.  The client could then read and write directly to/from that same database.

The first option is arguably the better one.  It's more flexible for future needs, providing a real-time method of communication with the service.  However, WCF can require a significant learning curve, so if you aren't already comfortable with WCF and option 2 meets your current needs, it's not a bad solution.

WCF works essentially like web services, but it's more powerful and far more configurable.  It is the solution to use if you need to expose methods like 'GetScanners' from a windows service, as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Steven. I had thought about using WCF, but it seems a bit overkill for what I'm trying to achieve. The barcode scanners are already talking to a web service which I intend to update to WCF (or web api). The only disadvantage with the database solution is speed- when the user scans a barcode they need an immediate response: which is what they get with the current app. Are service controllers a possibility? I've had a quick look at these but can't see any way of getting data out of the windows service?

Comment: I don't know anything about service controllers, but if real-time communication is necessary I'd say WCF would be the preferred method and would be worth the time-investment to learn the technology.  It's fairly simple to implement for simple tasks.  It's just that there are a lot of configuration options which can get a bit more complicated if you need to do more advanced things.  If you don't want to go that route, you could always just open a TCP/IP socket and communicate through the socket using your own custom protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your advice - I now have the shell of a WCF service hosted by the windows service. A separate application running on the PC is now able to access endpoints on the service. My question now is how does the service get information from the windows service.

Comment: i.e. I have a collection of barcode scanner objects - when a scan is received each barcode scanner raises an event. I want the event (containing the code scanned) passed to the WCF service. I can call a 'SetLastScan' endpoint which sends it to the WCF service but I can't see anywhere to set application level variables for the WCF service (allowing me to retrieve the last scan via a 'GetLastScan' endpoint. Sorry if I'm rambling, this is all new to me!

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly, you know how to add a GetLastScan endpoint to your service, but you don't know how to implement the server-side method to get the data to return to the client?

Comment: Sorted! I had to decorate my service class with: `<ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode:=ServiceModel.InstanceContextMode.Single)> _` This makes the service run as a single instance - variables set by the windows service can be read by the windows application! Thanks again for your advice.